# Regex Exclude Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to exclude some data from a string using regex.

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^(24 47(.*?)0D 0A)$");
```

The idea is to filter out and data starting with "24 47" and ending "0D 0A"

The source string:

```
A0 A1 00 02 83 00 83 0D 0A 
A0 A1 00 02 84 1B 9F 0D 0A 
24 47 50 47 47 41 2C 31 32 31 39 30 37 2E 30 30 30 2C 32 34 30 30 2E 30 30 30 30 2C 4E 2C 31 32 31 30 30 2E 30 30 30 30 2C 45 2C 30 2C 30 30 2C 30 2E 30 2C 30 2E 30 2C 4D 2C 30 2E 30 2C 4D 2C 2C 30 30 30 30 2A 36 35 0D 0A 
24 47 50 47 53 41 2C 41 2C 31 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 2C 30 2E 30 2C 30 2E 30 2C 30 2E 30 2A 33 30 0D 0A 
24 47 50 52 4D 43 2C 31 32 31 39 30 37 2E 30 30 30 2C 56 2C 32 34 30 30 2E 30 30 30 30 2C 4E 2C 31 32 31 30 30 2E 30 30 30 30 2C 45 2C 30 30 30 2E 30 2C 30 30 30 2E 30 2C 32 38 30 36 30 36 2C 2C 2C 4E 2A 37 34 0D 0A 
24 47 50 56 54 47 2C 30 30 30 2E 30 2C 54 2C 2C 4D 2C 30 30 30 2E 30 2C 4E 2C 30 30 30 2E 30 2C 4B 2C 4E 2A 30 32 0D 0A
```

But I only want this:

```
A0 A1 00 02 83 00 83 0D 0A 
A0 A1 00 02 84 1B 9F 0D 0A
```

Comment: Are you getting any wrong output?

Comment: The result always returns nothing. I'm trying to exclude the above pattern from the result?

Comment: This should work - what's your problem?

Comment: Ok, a bit more info. This is a binary feed from a GPS unit, represented as hex chars. the 24 47... OD OA is the "$G ... \n\r". The rest is the GPS unit command responses.

Comment: @Tim, my appologies... did comment about it lower down. Seems i tried to solve a problem the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex requires the *entire string* to start with "24 47" and end with "0D 0A". You want the multiline option that makes `^` and `$` match start/end of each line:

Try

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^24 47(.*)0D 0A$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

If you want to *exclude* those lines, then use a negative lookahead:

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^(?!24 47(.*)0D 0A$).*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

If you want to find and remove delimited substrings *anywhere* in a long, contiguous string without line breaks, try this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b24 47(.*?)0D 0A\b", "<removed>");
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` matches the start of a string and `$` matches the end. If you are considering that your "24 47" and "0D 0A" is in middle of your string then consider removing `^` and `$`.

```
var textFiltered = Regex.Replace(originalText, @"(24 47(.*?)\r\n)", "");
```

**UPDATE**

*TRY THIS, JUST TESTED:*

```
string replace = Regex.Replace(input, @"(24 47(.*?)0D 0A *(\r\n)*)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) instead of `Match`?

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^(24 47(.*?)0D 0A)$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to match the *special line characters* (CR and LF), you have to set the **options** to `Singleline`. And you have to **replace** with empty string.

```
 text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^(24 47(.*?)\r\n)$", "", RegexOptions.Singleline );
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, added the line breaks to illustrate the problem, not there in the source data.

Comment: @JandeJager: What? If you change your input, how should we build a matching regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list of strings, try to match the regex `^24 47.*0D 0A $`, and select those strings in case of which the match is **not** successful. Note the extra space before the `$`. The example strings you gave end with a space.